# Bulk Insert into elasticsearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, bulk

I am trying to import a large json file into elasticsearch in a local machine via the following command:

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @Filename.json

It worked previously and I imported several files, but recently I am getting below errors which should not be the case!

"curl: (55) Send failure: Broken pipe"

and

"HTTP content length exceeded 104857600 bytes."

I tried smaller file and also set "http.max_content_length: 500M" in the configuration file "elasticsearch.yml.

I do not get the same error message any more but process is not getting done completely, however I can see the data is inserted into the elastic search.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please refer https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2902

Comment: @Amit pore Thanks, I checked the post, not found any thing new to help me!

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: ES version 2.3.5

Comment: Sending whatever size of json file with operations in it will at one point be too much for your cluster. I suggest having a look at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html#_how_big_is_too_big) and consider the performance implications of creating too big bulk requests.